# How to adapt DFS for traversal of a m-ary Tree with non-unique node identifiers?

Tags: python, algorithm

I need to run DFS on a m-ary tree where different nodes have the same identifier. Furthermore, I need to visit all the nodes and not the de-duplicated version of the tree.

Suppose I define my m-ary tree (here binary for simplicity) as follows:

```
# the branch with parent node 2 appears twice in the tree
tree = {1: {2, 3}, 2: {4, 5}, 3: {2, 6}}
print(tree)
```

I would normally implement a DFS as follows i.e. accounting for visited nodes:

```
# initialize stack with root node
stack = [1]
visited = set()
# record the order
dfs = []
while stack:
    current = stack.pop()
    dfs.append(current)
    if current not in visited:
        visited.add(current)
        if current in tree:
           stack.extend(tree[current])
        else:
           # we have a leaf node
           pass

print(dfs)
```

which produces the following order which is correct but not what I want because it will ignore the second branch occurrence with parent 2:

```
[1, 3, 6, 2, 5, 4]
```

I could instead ignore the `visited` logic and directly do:

```
# initialize stack with root node
stack = [1]
# record the order
dfs = []
while stack:
    current = stack.pop()
    dfs.append(current)
    if current in tree:
        stack.extend(tree[current])
    else:
        # we have a leaf node
        pass

print(dfs)
```

which produces the desired following order:

```
[1, 3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 2, 5, 4]
```

Is there a border case I am missing when I get rid of the visited check?

Comment: Is it certain that the graph is a DAG?

Comment: @trincot good point, yes indeed it is a DAG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution (without `visited`) will work fine when it is guaranteed that the graph, that is formed by unique `id` nodes, has no cycles, i.e. it is a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

It will just give duplicate identifiers in the output. If there are *n* paths from the root to a certain node, then that node's identifier will occur *n* times in the output. Be aware that if a graph is [dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph), this may produce a large output.

Comment: Without a visited check, you need the graph to be a tree.

Comment: @MattTimmermans, that depends on the aim of the algorithm. The OP's example is not a tree. They seem to be OK with revisiting a node many times, and get their desired output without `visited`. The only constraint for making sure the algorithm *terminates*, is that it is a DAG.

Comment: Oh, you think the OP wants to perform DFS on the tree implied by assuming that the target of every reference is distinct.  OK, that seems to be the case, but I wouldn't want anyone to read this and think that DFS "works fine" on a DAG without a visited check.

Comment: Also warning: The output may be exponentially large.

Comment: @MattTimmermans, that warning is also in my answer.